# Словил майнер/вирус, переустановил виндовс, захожу в диспетчер и резко падает нагрузка, нормально ли это?

Tags: windows, процессор, вирусы, нагрузка

Такой вопрос, вчера поймал то ли вирус, то ли майнер, пытался удалить самостоятельно не помогло, ибо напросто не давал запустить даже доктор веб ( даже в безопасном режиме )

открывал диспетчер, после открытия нагрузка спадала и через несколько минут диспетчер закрывался, так же не мог заходить/смотреть/гуглить все что было связано с вирусами, автоматом закрывало.

Снес винду, заодно все диски, установил дрова, проблема с браузер ушла, спокойно могу гуглить наподобие "как удалить вирус" и тд.

Диспетчер не закрывается.

Но есть одно но, и это я хочу узнать у знатоков, открываю диспетчер значит, вновь столкнулся с нагрузкой, скажите пожалуйста это нормально?

То есть открыл диспетчер, резко нагрузка от 20% до 60% на процессор и спадывает до 0%-5%.

Можно ли сказать что вирус ( или же майнер ) удалился?

Пока искал информацию на форумах, наткнулся на такой комментарий, он был о том что есть шанс что майнер/вирус мог попасть в материнку, как тогда его прогнать с материнки?

Думаю проверить через видеокарту на вирус/майнер, ибо в ней есть функция, которая отвечает за начинание работы видюхи, то есть если комп не нагружен то она не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть ресурсы системы через Монитор ресурсов(Диспетчер задач>производительность>монитор ресурсов>закрыть диспетчер задач) или Process hacker

Answer (score 1):

Просто майнер-вирус прдолжает жить на Вашем компе.

И он типа "хитрый": при запущенном диспетчере задач и признаках наличия пользователя за компом - он перестаёт работать, "прячется".

я лично не думаю, что он попал "на материнку" - хотя современнные биосы действительн стали слишком умными...

скорее всего, при переустановке винды он откуда то попадает на ваш комп заново - через переустанавливаемые программы, через уязвимости в винде, с другого компа в локальной сети и т.п.

попробуйе сделать переустаовку, просто будьте повнимательнее.

Можно попробовать использовать Process Explorer из Sysinternals, он несколько "умнее" встроенного в винду.

PS. И главное - не паникуйте!

Винда после установки нет фреймворка некоторое время занимается "оптимизацией". Это значит, что система грузит процессор, а при начале работы человека за компом эта нагрузка спадает. Как видите, симптомы похожи на Ваши. Проходит само, просто дайте винде, как мутной воде, денёк "отстояться".